# iOS - Audio Output Endpoint Routing

Tags: ios, audio, routes, airplay

Is there a way create a virtual audio output device that would make it show up in the Music app's or Spotify's output options? Alternatively, is there a way to intercept the audio stream and then force audio output to something unused (say, open headphone port)?

What I want to do is take the raw audio stream, encode/compress it via a codec, and then send over BLE (not BT Classic). Ideally my "device", or service, would show up in the output options of the music/Spotify apps